# Add another condition for joining 2 data in 1 array

Tags: javascript

I am creating a matchmaking function where 2 players with the same weight will be paired.

It is currently working now based on the same weight. Now, I added another condition where players have their own level. My first condition is based on the same weight. This is working. My 2nd condition is level. So if the players have the same level, it will prioritize the level.

My question is, after prioritizing the level, is there a way where I can also match the players who are not on the same level?

My current function works only on the same level, but if it's not on the same level, it will be no longer in pair.

```js
const source = [
  {
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [], // changed these to arrays
    level: 1,
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [],
    level: 2,
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: "player3",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [],
    level: 1,
  },
    {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: "player4",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [],
    level: 2,
  },
    { 
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: "player5",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [],
    level: 4,
  },
   { 
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: "player6",
    weight: 1900,
    noFight: [],
    level: 5,
  },
];

console.log ( combine(source) )

function combine( data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2 ) 
{
const 
groups        = []
, related       = []
, sortedData    = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight)
, alreadyInRela = (setX,eName) =>
{
let list = [...setX, eName] 
return related.some(rela=>list.every(l=>rela.has(l)))
};
sortedData.forEach((el,indx)=>
{
let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
    g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
        && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
        && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different 
        && el.level == g.level  // this is what i added for level.
        && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName ) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
        && !el.noFight.some(noFightEl => g.indxs.map(gi => sortedData[gi].entryID).includes(noFightEl))  // is el.noFight having any of group item
    )
if (place < 0) // not found -> create new group
  {
  let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
  groups.push( { names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight, level: el.level } )  // group constitutive info 
  related.push( names )                                      // keep track of group list
  }
else // find a place in a group
  {
  groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
  groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
  }
})
return groups.reduce((r,g,i)=> // build result
{
  if (g.indxs.length > 1) {
    let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x=>sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
    r[key] = []
    g.indxs.forEach(x=> r[key].push( sortedData[x]) )
  }
  return r
}, {} )
}
```

Current output (As we can see here, player 5 and 6 are not paired because they don't have the same level):

```
{
  0_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  level: 1,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player3",
  level: 1,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}],
  1_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player2",
  level: 2,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player4",
  level: 2,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}]
}
```

Target output (As we can see, players 5 and 6 got paired, this is my target where it prioritizes first the players with level, if there is no more same level to be paired with, it will be paired to the players who have the same weight or closes level):

```
   {
  0_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  level: 1,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player3",
  level: 1,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}],
  1_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player2",
  level: 2,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player4",
  level: 2,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}],
2_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 5,
  entryName: "player5",
  level: 4,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 6,
  entryName: "player6",
  level: 5,
  noFight: [],
  weight: 1900
}
```

Comment: That is an unusual coding style. Omitting semicolons is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This two-step coupling should give you the desired result:

```js
const source = [
  {
entryID: 1,
entryName: "player1",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [], // changed these to arrays
level: 1,
  },
  {
entryID: 2,
entryName: "player2",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 2,
  },
  {
entryID: 3,
entryName: "player3",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 1,
  },
{
entryID: 4,
entryName: "player4",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 2,
  },
{ 
entryID: 5,
entryName: "player5",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 4,
  },
   { 
entryID: 6,
entryName: "player6",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 5,
  },
   { 
entryID: 7,
entryName: "player7",
weight: 1900,
noFight: [],
level: 8,
  }
];

function couples(da,a=[],ignlvl=false){
 da.forEach((one,i,ar)=>
  ar.slice(i+1).some(two=>{
  if(!two.paired && !one.paired &&(ignlvl||one.level==two.level) && one.weight==two.weight) {
   one.paired=two.paired=1;
   a.push([one,two]);
 }})
)
return a;
}

const res=couples(source,couples(source),1);
source.forEach(e=>delete e.paired); // clear the paired flag ...
console.log(res);
```

I added a seventh player with a similar weight into the sample data in order to demonstrate that a surplus entry will actually be left behind, uncoupled.